# Ideographic space encoding

Tags: c#, encode, html-encode

I want to exclude the ideographic space on our encoding but it's not working.

```
string a = "A　B";
var encoder = HtmlEncoder.Create(allowedRanges: new[] { UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin, new UnicodeRange(3000, 1) });

Console.WriteLine(encoder.Encode(a));
```

Output is

```
A&#x3000;B
```

I'm expecting to show as a space only. The reason is i'm sending it on another application and they want to it to receive as it is.

```
A　B
```

Comment: What did you expect to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE's code point is 3000, but that is in *hex*, so you should have written:

```
new UnicodeRange(0x3000, 1)
```

However, this won't fix the problem.

If you look at the "Remarks" of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.htmlencoder.create?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Encodings_Web_HtmlEncoder_Create_System_Text_Unicode_UnicodeRange___) for `Create`, you'll see:

> Some characters in `allowedRanges` might still be encoded; that is, this parameter indicates what ranges the encoder is allowed to not encode, not what characters it must not encode.

That sucks, doesn't it?

If we have a look at the [reference source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.Encodings.Web/System/Text/Encodings/Web/HtmlEncoder.cs,07bf6ee73cdc2538,references), we see that there is a comment specifically saying to *forbid* all characters in certain categories (this constructor is called by `Create`):

```
public DefaultHtmlEncoder(TextEncoderSettings settings)
    {
        if (settings == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));
        }

        _allowedCharacters = settings.GetAllowedCharacters();

        // Forbid codepoints which aren't mapped to characters or which are otherwise always disallowed
        // (includes categories Cc, Cs, Co, Cn, Zs [except U+0020 SPACE], Zl, Zp)
        _allowedCharacters.ForbidUndefinedCharacters();
```

We see that all the characters in `Zs` except the 0x20 space is forbidden. Since this is written in the source code, and after the line `_allowedCharacters = settings.GetAllowedCharacters();`, you can't change the behaviour no matter how you change the settings.

So in conclusion, you can't use `HtmlEncoder` to do this. You'd have to use something else.

---

The old `WebUtility.HtmlEncode` seems to *not* encode ideographic space, but it also doesn't encode other spaces... Maybe that is useful to you?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I had no choice but to use the `HtmlDecoder` on the entire object when I'm sending it to third party application since I can't rely on `allowedRanges`.